# Adding media to a question - audio, video?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

It would be great if SO would enable attaching media snippets to a question: I currently have a question I would like to open, about a bad `.wav` file I generated with webRTC, and I simply cannot explain it in words - only **hearing** the file content would make people understand my issue. I guess this also goes for some video issues.

I know I can upload the file somewhere and attach a link, but it makes the question posting more complicated.

Have SO considered allowing small media snippets attachments to questions?

Comment: What exactly is the complication in attaching a link? Also - if you uploaded to youtube and provided a link it gets auto-embedded anyway...

Comment: @JonClements Why is attaching a photo or a screenshot possible? For that exact same reason - make things easier.

Comment: Well - they're also hosted by a 3rd party service (and are applicable in more cases than audio/video - so is made slightly more convenient) but the editor just knows how to preview them. And how small is small? A few minutes of audio/video all adds up and would require SE to cater for storage or a 3rd party to do so - both of which would cost. For the number of people that would need/use this plus all the complications in maintainence etc... When you can just copy a link if you need to do it... What benefit is there?

Comment: @JonClements I will not go into SO decisions on what to spend money on, but storage is so cheap today I think it should be considered. In my case, I cannot open the question easily.

Comment: The sites (AFAIK) aren't setup to deal with media storage full stop (more just markdown) - that'd be a fundamental change - not the cost of storage itself. Besides what difficulty are you having creating a youtube video and copy pasting the link?

Comment: I can see how this might be very useful for a helpdesk, but SO is not a helpdesk.  Also, I doubt very much that those using smartphones with limited data tariffs would want large media snippets embedded in questions in such a way that they had to be downloaded:(

Comment: How do you spell/grammar check a media audio channel?

Comment: How do I know that any link is not spam before I open it?

Comment: *I simply cannot explain it in words - only hearing the file content would make people understand my issue.* If you link to it, someone else might be able to sufficiently explain how it's wrong/garbled/whatever in words. I still occasionally get surprised that there's a term for something I never knew how to describe.

Answer (score 14):

We are not planning on adding support for uploading more types of content here, in particular something as niche as this (it is very specialised and would likely only ever be used by a tiny proportion of posts).

This is before we discuss things like security, bandwidth and hosting, none of which are trivial.

> I know I can upload the file somewhere and attach a link, but it makes the question posting more complicated.

This would be what I'd suggest indeed - there's just not enough usage for a feature of this sort for us to put in the time and effort in implementing it at this time.

Comment: I understing your concern but right now I am practicing with OpenCV motion detection and cannot interact with users because of my inability to post a 10sec 720p mp4 that should be the input needed by my script and that would be essentila to have a nice MRE anybody could play with

Answer (score 5):

The precise effects of these sort of changes are hard to predict, but one potential problem I see with this is that it will make it very easy for people to post their video as a question.

Part of my day job as a programmer is to help out our support team when they're struggling with a question, and you'd be surprised how often people ask a question by just sending a video. You're lucky if it's accompanied with a text description or sound to explain what's going on – usually you're left guessing. We've even had someone send us a video that consisted almost entirely out of him typing in Notepad (with a liberal amount of errors and use of backspace). It was one of the most ridiculous (and funny!) things I've ever seen.

Writing a coherent question is hard; making a vague video is easy.

On Stack Overflow there is also some precedence for this. consider the many questions that contain only a screenshot of the code, command, and/or error.

I'm not sure if this will be a significant problem, but it's something that would need to be considered.

All in all, I'm not sure if it's worth the effort and risk since the amount of questions with valid use of audio or video content are very low, and that there are already and abundance of free platforms that support such content (and can be linked to).

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. Again, in my case - only hearing the audio file can make my question understandable, but I see where your'e coming from. Have a great day.

Comment: Asking a support question by a video editing text is super weird. Surely copy-pasting text is easier than create a screencast? Specially for non-technical people?

Comment: @hasen relevant https://xkcd.com/763/

Comment: Making a video is pretty easy @hasen, loads of online services and such for it. Writing a text description of your problem is a lot harder/more time-consuming.

Answer (score -3):

If you keep it short, this can be already done, at least on SE sites that allow code snippets. You just need to convert the file to base64 and use HTML5. E.g.

```html
<audio autoplay controls src="data:audio/mpeg;base64,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">
  The “audio” tag does not appear to be supported by your browser.
</audio>
```

Comment: The code alone is 23000 characters. That's only 7000 left on the post length restriction at 30k.

Comment: There is no way I run that code snippet.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Eh, I can understand hesitation if you don't know HTML, but since all of the base64 part is in an src attribute, with no quotation mark interruption, in a standard HTML5 audio element, if such text could ever ever break out of that src attribute without a closing double quotation mark, or the data prefaced w/"data:audio/mpeg" could be interpreted as anything except audio, that'd mean your browser had a pretty serious 0-day that threatened it just about wherever it went on the web. I admit people who can't interpret it shouldn't get used to clicking such things, though.

Comment: @Zoe That's enough not to interfere with most questions. At any rate, it shows how easily SE could include it as a dedicated feature if there was a will. Some old answers to related meta questions remark that HTML5 or any single audio format isn't well supported, which is [no longer true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats). If there ever was a dedicated SE feature, it probably shouldn't allow more than, say, 20kB (compressed) of audio per sample anyway. That'd be enough for word pronunciation answers, etc.

Comment: nice passive aggressive interpretation of my skills lol.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier That's really not how I meant it; I apologize that it came off that way. I honestly assumed you just didn't know HTML (which would be no fault), and were wisely in the habit of not running unrecognized code. I also thought your comment correctly indicated a problem with making this a common practice --  that others could use such snippets but put in a script. In this particular case, it's fairly verifiable that there's nothing amiss, barring the existence of some terrible unkown mp3 interpretation vulnerability, so "there's no way" seemed extreme if you could parse it.

Comment: Oh, thanks for saying that. S'all good.