# Why does Stack Exchange use Imgur to host images?

Tags: discussion, images

Why does Stack Exchange use Imgur to host Images? What are the advantages of it?

Stack Exchange pays Imgur for their service. So why can't Stack Exchange save images on their own site, Stack Exchange? Would the cost be higher than what they pay for Imgur?

But I don't think that money is the key. Generally, Stack Exchange storing images on Imgur means they are little bit dependent on Imgur (their servers may be down or lost data or anything). So that is a disadvantage.

So why does Stack Exchange choose to save images on Imgur instead of their own servers?

Comment: This is why: [Any details about stack.imgur.com?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/90342)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have already read that post. But it did not give a answer for my question. That's why I asked it.

Comment: Also relevant: [Is stack.imgur.com hosting still free for Stack Exchange?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/213547)

Comment: Image hosting is a specialty, why re-invent that wheel?

Comment: @MartijnPieters When thinking about all features of SE, is it a big deal manage and image hosting?

Comment: I'd say it is probably cost-effective to have the images hosted there. Images are binary data, posts are text. The two require very different hosting setups.

Comment: This question got 3,4 down votes I think. Please can anyone explain me to reason for it? So it is helpful for me to prevent asking such type of questions.

Comment: You forgot to include your research which made users think that you asked a badly researched question. Also the why of things is not always that interesting. That could be an explanation of the down votes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> is it a big deal manage and image hosting?

It is. There are lots of bandwidth, caching and storage concerns, imgur also provides image resizing services for uploaded images.

It isn't trivial to design and run an image hosting service that handles Stack Exchange volume of traffic and images.

Sure, we *could* do it if we had to, but that would take a bunch of people a bunch of time to design, implement, deploy and support. For something that isn't a core of what we do (which is mostly dealing with text).

As [Martijn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) [commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350433/why-does-stack-exchange-use-imgur-to-host-images#comment480250_350433), why reinvent the wheel?

We are aware that this is a third party dependency, but given how rock-solid it has been for us, we are OK with the trade off.

Comment: I don't know if you've seen or want to provide a response on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350207/adding-media-to-a-question-audio-video - it's similar...

Comment: @JonClements - not seen that. We won't support uploads of random types of content, especially something as niche as this. Will give an answer there.