# Ban photobucket.com images

Tags: discussion, feature-request, images, banning

I just noticed that many photobucket pictures will now display as:

[image: photobucket disable 3rd party hosting]

So I feel we are in a similar situation as: [Ban ImageShack Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300232/ban-imageshack-images)

Related: [Search for photobucket URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A**.photobucket.com)

Note on re-uploading images: it is generally not permitted to re-upload someone else images from photobucket, as they aren't licensed for that. Source: http://support.photobucket.com/hc/en-us/articles/200724104-Using-Photos-Found-on-Photobucket

Comment: [Not unrelated question on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299589/295232)

Comment: *No photos for you!*

Comment: With all the extra money they get, perhaps they can buy some hyphens and more lower-case letters for their copy.

Comment: Can we consider images, uploaded to photobucked for the sole purpose of displaying them on SO, to be _"Subscriber Content"_ and therefore licensed under CC-SA?

Comment: I notice the quality of ads on photobucket just forces you to use adblock. If you don't, prepare for malware and scareware and adware drive bys

Comment: Real question: is there any reason to allow *any* image hosting other than SO's?

Comment: @jpmc26 Perhaps it's legacy support for posts with images [before SO hosting](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support). It may also be file type support, Imgur (SO image hosting provider) has _slightly_ [limited support](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000083326-What-files-can-I-upload-What-is-the-size-limit-) and AFAIK doesn't support SVG, SO posts may use embed SVG's from Wikipedia articles.

Comment: I'm surprised that imageshack.us was banned before photobucket... a lot of project sites I've worked with left photobucket for imageshack back in the late 00s because photobucket kept making harmful changes to UX and ease of access to the photos.

Comment: @jpmc26: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350433/why-does-stack-exchange-use-imgur-to-host-images

Comment: @AmitJoshi That answers why SO doesn't implement its own image hosting. It does not answer why they allow users to reference images anywhere other than the solution they use.

Comment: I'm all for banning it. They caused me many headaches with their unannounced money grab, and I've gone through a few dozen of my old posts so far to fix the image links. One problem: since many of the posts the links appear on are from "the before time, the long, long ago", many are locked as "historically significant" and can't be edited to fix the broken link.

Comment: I'd say on a given day, reading up on any given subject via discussion searches using Google, PhotoBucket missing image errors easily comprise the most bit-rot of all results found.  They are going to be remembered for decades, although probably not in the way they'd like.

Comment: Yes, please ban links to this website entirely. They’re constantly going dead.

Comment: @jpmc26 I have an answer with some links to an SVG that I keep in my Dropbox account, since imgur doesn’t support SVGs. I keep some imgur links in the post history in case my Dropbox links ever go dead, though.

Comment: @gnovice I think you should post that as an answer. It warrants the attention and some discussion around possible solutions.

Comment: @Carrosive and AlexisKing Good points. I kind of figured there were reasons against it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you think SO has enough clout with Imgur to ask them to support SVG? Do we know why Imgur doesn't allow SVG images?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler maybe ask StackOverflow to accept [the HTML <svg> element](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_inhtml.asp)? Different question anyway.

Comment: @gnovice You can flag those posts for moderator attention so that a moderator can edit them.

Comment: How such services can even exist? They feed on people who don't read licences and stuff... *that most people don't read*. Must say they're just **lame**.

Answer (score 16):

I'm all for banning images from photobucket. They caused me many headaches with their unannounced money grab, and I've gone through a few dozen of my old posts so far to fix the image links.

While it's true that the links will work fine for an account that has paid the extra money to allow third-party hosting, this carries a lot of uncertainty. What if the account owner decides at some point in the future that they don't want to continue to pay the fee? The validity of the links is dependent on the actions of the account owner, thus making them undependable.

In addition to stopping new links, we still have to fix the old ones. Since quite a few of the posts the broken links appear on are from "the before time, the long, long ago", many are locked as "historically significant" and can't be edited to fix the broken link. I have all my images that *were* on photobucket, but I can't update them on these locked questions. Should we have some kind of scheduled clean-up initiative during which they will be unlocked, or just handle them one-at-a-time by flagging a mod for assistance? Or just say "screw it" since the questions are locked anyway?

Comment: Agreed.  To me, it makes sense to ban all external resources and links in answers not provided simply as an authoritative reference.  Since there is no guarantee external resources will be maintained and static for perpetuity, it's to ensure the highest content integrity on Stack.

Answer (score -15):

I guess you could disable the images showing on existing topics apart from "high ranking" users and let those users decide if there are available alternatives to edit in during the cleanup

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?