# Can Stack Overflow use a different domain for images instead of stack.imgur.com?

Tags: support, feature-request, image-upload, imgur

The images uploaded by users are not displayed in Turkey because of the imgur block.

The image link use a sub domain name like https://i.stack.imgur.com. Is it possible to assign a new domain to images like abc.com so that the users which live in countries that have imgur block may access image content?

I know there are some options like vpn, proxy etc. But this time for example if you use a free proxy than some of the site functionality doesn't work. For example some piece of javascript code doesn't work as excepted behind proxy.

So this question is not about what are my options to access blocked content.I wonder whether may SO support team may do something to enable access from blocked countries server side.

Because it looks a minor problem. If images have a stackoverflow subdomain or a new domain I don't think they'd block the image content.

My questions are whether something should be done server side not client side. Also wikipedia is blocked and it is possible to access it somehow. But in this case it becomes quite difficult to access site so I rarely use it. This is also the situation for stackoverflow network.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/imgur-com-blocked-what-are-my-options

Comment: Also google "turkey internet vpn" to find workarounds.

Comment: Using a different domain will cost them some resources but why the unnecessary change when  you can experiment with VPN's to find the best one for you.

Comment: That would be giving the censors exactly what they want. Diverting business away from imgur because turkey's authoritarian goverment has decided to ban it is the wrong response, imo.

Comment: Let's suppose they change the domain. How much time will it take for them to block the new domain?

Comment: Using a VPN seems to be the only solution here. Changing domains will do nothing good. You can also use tor for browsing anonymously

Comment: @Magisch while I'm not suggesting we should bend for whatever governments dream up, how exactly would serving the images through an SE domain be diverting business away from imgur? I mean, none of the users on SE need an imgur account  nor does imgur know who I am. I'm not using their business as far as I'm concerned. From a technical point of view it is feasible. The business argument doesn't make sense to me. Care to elaborate on that a bit for me?

Comment: @rene Well, for a start, SE pays imgur for that services.

Comment: @Tom yes, they do. SE can still use their services and pay for them but only serve those images from an SE domain. That will give lots of performance headaches but that by itself doesn't change the contract and/or business SE does with imgur.

Comment: @magish, I don't think the op is suggesting using a different service, only a different domain. imgur can still host the images and be paid for their service but if images.imgur.stackoverflow.com ends up being some kind of alias for i.stack.imgur.com not sure what the harm is.

Comment: Let's note that imgur.com is also blocked in China. Oh, and https://commons.wikimedia.org is blocked too of course.

Comment: Perhaps Stack Overflow could implement an image proxy that is enabled only for accounts in Turkey/China/etc.

Comment: @Cœur every language wikipedia is blocked in china https://ooni.torproject.org/post/2019-china-wikipedia-blocking/

Comment: @window.document as long as it's not a *.imgur.com domain, there's no reason for it to be blocked.

Comment: _For example, some piece of javascript code doesn't work as excepted behind proxy_ shouldn't this be a bug? Also yea @IanKemp I think so it is true, but to actually show that imgur backs StackExchange, the domain has to be like that.

Comment: Coding from Turkey I had the same problem. At some point I've ended up setting up VPN to route only traffic to blocked sites (e.g. Wikipedia, Imgur...) and use a direct connection for anything else. Then I've also found out that, unless I'm browsing something inside Turkey (physically) VPN is actually *faster* for everything so I've ended up keeping VPN on. If you've got some credits at AWS/Azure/GCP or a few dollars to spend, setup a personal OpenVPN server at West Europe and use there.

Comment: Same problem from Iran. The VPN solution works sometimes, I said sometimes because they are blocking VPNs too. I think I have 10-11 VPN application installed on my PC and most of the time none of them work. It's really hard to understand Q/A that contains explanation on images.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Yes bro, that is exactly what I did... Having your own VPN server seems to be the best idea if you are a programmer working in Turkey.

Comment: There is no technical solution to your problem. The solution is to demonstrate on the streets.

Comment: @Lundin unfortunately that works only if you have true democracy, not 'so-called democracy' as in Turkey.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu You overthrow dictatorships by protesting against them in public. Which is obviously easier said than done, takes lot of bravery. At any rate, fixing Turkey isn't SO's mission, nor is it to support its censorship.

Comment: @window.document If they block imgur as a whole, there's a decent chance they won't have a problem with an alias which only accesses a small part of it. Especially considering that those images belong to this professional network and imgur has lots of ... well, let's call them "unprofessional" images. I don't approve of such bans, of course, and VPNs are good, but requiring client-side applications to have the site be fully functional is not a great solution.

Comment: @Dukeling imgur is blocked as a whole in these countries and yes requiring client-side solutions to access the site is not a great solution. Still, they have to use VPN's which as mentioned in the question makes the javascript to misbehave. Also, no one approves of such bans, Wikipedia is banned in China, no one approves of it

Comment: They can even put images on any other platform and link it in the question.

Comment: **This is not a duplicate of [Imgur.com blocked, what are my options?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261455/5211833).** It is a *feature request* to SE as a whole to ask about another image provider. The OP already clearly states that they are not asking about what can be done client-side, rather whether SE is willing to make a server-side change.

Comment: @window.document close votes and up/down votes are not for the same reason. A question can get upvotes whilst still being off-topic/a duplicate etc.

Comment: @window.document, there are 17 downvotes. I personally think what while switching is possible (for new posts to use new service) they will still have problem with old posts. And migrating all old images to a new host is.. lots of work. What if Imgur is banned in Turkey and new service will be banned in e.g. Russia? Should SO always switch and switch? Rather fix original problem: lift the ban. Maybe missing pictures would be the last thing before revolution occurs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Imgur.com blocked, what are my options?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/imgur-com-blocked-what-are-my-options)

Comment: @Cerbrus This is a feature request. It has a proposal to solve the problem. Not a dupe, this question is not even asking what to do. The OP knows what to do

Comment: It _is_ a duplicate, because a change of host / domain ___isn't an option___. There's nothing that can be done server-side that __can't__ have major side-effects. (If something _can_ have major side effects, it's too big of a risk). Just like the non-canonical answer to _"I want downvotes to have a comment"_, this feature request can be dupe-closed of _"No, here's what you do instead"_.

Comment: @Cerbrus "It is a duplicate, because a change of host / domain isn't an option" - if this isn't an option, it should get declined, ideally with an explanation of why it's not an option, not closed as a duplicate of something proposing alternatives.

Comment: Change of host is never an option, but the change of a domain can be an option and does not require any other workarounds. @Cerbrus

Comment: @Dukeling: Feature requests to make comments mandatory when downvoting are dupe-closed with a _"no, and here's why not"_ canonical. This case is very similar.

Comment: @Cerbrus the post you linked neither answers it (yes or no, as there is no question) nor explains why not. Its a related post, just that. Consider answering the question if thats what you want.

Comment: @window.document: And then the censor has won. And the new domain will be blocked. Changing the domain isn't a solution.

Comment: I've cleaned up a bunch of comments here that were getting way too hostile and veering off topic. Let's keep things calm and focused on the question.

Comment: Not to be picky but there are people who live elsewhere in the world that have the same issue on worlk/school networks that block imgur domains by defaults

Comment: @JoeW: the issue and it’s solutions aren’t different for those users, though.

Answer (score 14):

First of all, I'm assuming the block on imgur's domain *also* includes their related IP addresses. I can't confirm this, as I'm not behind some kind of firewall.

This means a simple DNS setting that points an url like `images.stackoverflow.com` to a imgur IP would be ineffective, as those images would still be blocked based on the resolved IP.

As a result, all image traffic would have to go *through* SE's servers one way or another, adding a significant load to Stack Exchange's servers.

A load that imgur is specialized to handle, and SE isn't<sup>(*)</sup>. Of course I'm not an SE employee, but I'm pretty certain that handling this extra load isn't trivial or cheap. Image hosting wasn't outsourced [just for fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/).

---

If these blocks don't include imgur IP addresses, a simple local (client-side) change would be to redirect imgur domains to their IPs, but that seems too easy.

---

<sup>(*)</sup>[Oded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded) has written an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350434/1835379) that explains why [Stack Exchange uses Imgur to host images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350433/why-does-stack-exchange-use-imgur-to-host-images) At time of writing, that answer is nearly 2 years old, but it does mention Stack Exchange's volume of traffic to be a factor in this decision.

Comment: Also, if the block doesn't include IP addresses _today_, it doesn't mean that the block won't be extended later to include such IP addresses if there is an increase of traffic on those. This is especially true with the Great Firewall of China which dynamically adapts the layers of protection depending on the volume of traffic, type of traffic and more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this makes sense. Hopefully someone from the company can corroborate.

Answer (score 0):

My country also block imgur, and to solve that I added this string to `/etc/hosts` file:

```
104.16.24.34      i.stack.imgur.com
107.21.3.138      apidocs.imgur.com
151.101.36.193    api.imgur.com
104.16.53.111     help.imgur.com
151.101.36.193    blog.imgur.com
52.23.39.2        browserevents.imgur.com
151.101.36.193    p.imgur.com
151.101.36.193    s.imgur.com
151.101.36.193    store.imgur.com
151.101.36.193    i.imgur.com
151.101.60.193    imgur.com
```